# Android Notification Builder Sound

Tags: android, notifications

Im using a Notifiation builder and want sound, vibration and light.
vibration and light works fine but the sound doesnt wanna play. I tried many solutions here but most of em are for the deprecated version.
in the code below u can see what im doing. i tried both alamsound and sound but none worked.
do i need any permission ?

```
    public void createTestNotification(){
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
    NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.uks.uksnavigation/" + R.raw.notification);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction("nachricht");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

    Notification.Builder mBuilder =
            new Notification.Builder(getActivity())
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_mail_aktiv)
            .setContentTitle("New Message")
            .setContentText("Nachrichten text text text")
            .setSound(sound)
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);

    nm.notify(1, mBuilder.build());     


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.uks.uksnavigation/raw/notification")`.